# What is temporal memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am studying expression templates and the mshadow codebase. In their wiki pages [here](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/tree/master/guide/exp-template#a-naive-bad-solution), they provide an example that is bad solution because its doing temporal memory allocation and deallocation. What is that and how is the given code doing such a thing?

Referred Code :

```
// Naive solution for vector operation overloading 
struct Vec {
  int len;
  float* dptr;
  Vec(int len) : len(len) { 
    dptr = new float[len];
  }
  Vec(const Vec& src) : len(src.len) {
    dptr = new float[len];
    memcpy(dptr, src.dptr, sizeof(float)*len ); 
  }
  ~Vec(void) {
    delete [] dptr;
  }
};

inline Vec operator+(const Vec &lhs, const Vec &rhs) {
  Vec res(lhs.len);
  for (int i = 0; i < lhs.len; ++i) {
    res.dptr[i] = lhs.dptr[i] + rhs.dptr[i];
  } 
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Don't link to code. All relevant code should be *in* the question.

Comment: Don't sand us to look for your question, you can add a code here.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case they are talking about allocating some space in memory to hold values temporarily.

For example, when you do

```
a = a + b;
```

the compiler will do the following

1. allocate a new memory block
2. calculate the sum of `a` and `b` and write the result into that block
3. copy the result from the temporary storage into `a`

As you can see there was no reason to do #1 or #3, because the value of the sum can actually go directly into `a`.

Now you may ask: Why can't the compiler understand that `a=a+b` and `a+=b` are the same things. And the answer is because although for the `int`, `double`, `size_t` this is always true, one could implement a class where those two operators do something different. Take a look at how `std::ofstream` uses left bitshift operator for something completely different.